# How to remove the line that start with bunch of tabs/spaces notepad++

Tags: notepad++

My text file contain something like this

```
  asd signal1;/* '<Root>/explain1' */
  asd signal2;/* '<Root>/explain2' */
  asd signal3;
                                    /* '<Root>/explain3' */
  asd signal4;
                                    /* '<Root>/explain4' */
  asd signal5;/* '<Root>/explain5' */
```

How do I used replace (Ctrl + H) to remove all the end of lines and the space in next line to make them to something like this?

```
  asd signal1;/* '<Root>/explain1' */
  asd signal2;/* '<Root>/explain2' */
  asd signal3;/* '<Root>/explain3' */
  asd signal4;/* '<Root>/explain4' */
  asd signal5;/* '<Root>/explain5' */
```

I tried to google how to do it but there's nothing close to what I'm looking for

Comment: If you have a known pattern, you can use REGEX, but building the exact statement would  be tricky since you aren't searching for a value but a lack of one.

Comment: If you could feed the values into a front end like asp classic, python or php you might be able to put the values into some sort of grid so that it knows when it finds a space to then reformat the data properly.  Then when you have it worked out, you could have it output the file using the FileObject to create a new text file that happens to have all the data formatted properly.

Comment: In the case of your example you could use regex matching with `;\s+` and replace with `;`. However hard to say if that is fool proof for your actual data

Comment: UPDATE - oh you know .. was thinking about it and re-read your post.  Title says its TABS .. so if the tabs are actually in the file, you can use the REGEX to search for \t for a single tab for example.  I tested what you posted, and it formats into spaces instead of tabs .. so hopefully that is just due to typing the example and not copy and paste.

Comment: I used REGEX with this
\R++(  )

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error, I found that the following pattern seems to work:

```
;\s+(.*?)(?=\r?\n|$)
```

This matches:

- `;` a semicolon
- `\s+` one or more whitespace characters
- `(.*?)` then match AND capture in `$1` all content until
- `(?=\r?\n|$)` looking ahead and seeing the nearest newline or end of input

### Demo

The replacement is `;$1`, which effectively strips all whitespace after the assembly command but before the C style comment.

Note: Run the above regex in dot all mode, so that the `(.*?)` term can match across newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++ you could use:

```
;\K\s+
```

The pattern matches:

- `;` Match the semicolon
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\s+` Match one or more whitespace characters that also matches newlines

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQYyAm/1).

In the replacement use an empty string.

---

If you want to make it a bit more precise, you can assert `/*` to the right using a positive lookahead:

```
;\K\s+(?=/\*)
```

[image]